# Applying same algorithm to various input files in QGIS modeler?

Tags: qgis, batch, qgis-modeler

I wonder what´s the best way to create a ROI (by clipping algorithm) for all bands of one LANDSAT scene in QGIS graphical modeler.

Is there a way that avoids listing all (raster) bands and applying the algorithm to each?
something similiar to batch processing?